# How to make repeated column values columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Here is the dataset that I have. The items below are recorded on a daily basis.

Cigarettes, Tobacco, Snack/Grocery, Beverages, Milk, Coffee, Solaray, Prepared Foods, International Foods, Automotive/NewsPaper, Lottery - Scratch, Lottery - Machine, Whl-Sales/Gift-Card are repeated per date.

I want to transform this frame to one that covers the same data, with the repeated departments as columns, Date as index and Sales as the values. 
I tried using pivot_table, but I realized it changes the values, the combination. 
This is how I thought about it, but it returned unexpected results...

```
dept = dept.pivot_table(values='Sales', index = dept.index, columns='Dept', aggfunc='first')
```

and here is the original dataframe that I want to change.

```
Date                   Dept        Sales
2018-12-01             Cigarettes  426.889
2018-12-01                Tobacco    43.84
2018-12-01          Snack/Grocery   198.57
2018-12-01              Beverages   160.97
2018-12-01                   Milk    11.56
2018-12-01                 Coffee    29.72
2018-12-01                Solaray     9.99
2018-12-01         Prepared Foods     3.99
2018-12-01     International Food       65
2018-12-01                 Sweets        0
2018-12-01  Automotive/News Paper    10.47
2018-12-01      Lottery - Scratch     1397
2018-12-01      Lottery - Machine      191
2018-12-01    Whl-Sales/Gift-Card        0
2018-12-01                  Total     2549
2018-12-02             Cigarettes   374.01
2018-12-02                Tobacco    89.29
2018-12-02          Snack/Grocery   178.01
2018-12-02              Beverages   135.28
2018-12-02                   Milk     9.57
2018-12-02                 Coffee    33.76
2018-12-02                Solaray    17.99
2018-12-02         Prepared Foods    20.98
2018-12-02     International Food     3.98
2018-12-02                 Sweets        0
2018-12-02  Automotive/News Paper    13.16
2018-12-02      Lottery - Scratch      651
2018-12-02      Lottery - Machine      211
2018-12-02    Whl-Sales/Gift-Card        0
2018-12-02                  Total  1738.03
2018-12-03             Cigarettes   463.54
2018-12-03                Tobacco    35.26
2018-12-03          Snack/Grocery   164.19
2018-12-03              Beverages   126.01
2018-12-03                   Milk     8.57
2018-12-03                 Coffee    30.47
2018-12-03                Solaray    17.99
2018-12-03         Prepared Foods        0
2018-12-03     International Food    21.98
2018-12-03                 Sweets        0
2018-12-03  Automotive/News Paper    70.17
2018-12-03      Lottery - Scratch     1046
2018-12-03      Lottery - Machine      461
2018-12-03    Whl-Sales/Gift-Card        0
2018-12-03                  Total  2445.18
2018-12-03             Cigarettes   463.54
2018-12-03                Tobacco    35.26
2018-12-03          Snack/Grocery   164.19
2018-12-03              Beverages   126.01
2018-12-03                   Milk     8.57
2018-12-03                 Coffee    30.47
2018-12-03                Solaray    17.99
2018-12-03         Prepared Foods        0
2018-12-03     International Food    21.98
2018-12-03                 Sweets        0
2018-12-03  Automotive/News Paper    70.17
2018-12-03      Lottery - Scratch     1046
2018-12-03      Lottery - Machine      461
2018-12-03    Whl-Sales/Gift-Card        0
2018-12-03                  Total  2445.18
2018-12-04             Cigarettes   291.91
2018-12-04                Tobacco    42.93
2018-12-04          Snack/Grocery   207.87
2018-12-04              Beverages   163.11
2018-12-04                   Milk     3.99
2018-12-04                 Coffee    32.17
2018-12-04                Solaray    40.98
2018-12-04         Prepared Foods        5
2018-12-04     International Food     6.98
2018-12-04                 Sweets        0
2018-12-04  Automotive/News Paper       47
2018-12-04      Lottery - Scratch      762
2018-12-04      Lottery - Machine   112.75
2018-12-04    Whl-Sales/Gift-Card      NaN
2018-12-04                  Total  1716.69
2018-12-05             Cigarettes   255.72
2018-12-05                Tobacco    81.52
2018-12-05          Snack/Grocery   212.94
2018-12-05              Beverages    87.94
2018-12-05                   Milk     9.77
2018-12-05                 Coffee    15.95
2018-12-05                Solaray    11.98
2018-12-05         Prepared Foods     8.98
2018-12-05     International Food    17.73
2018-12-05                 Sweets        0
2018-12-05  Automotive/News Paper    46.24
2018-12-05      Lottery - Scratch      540
2018-12-05      Lottery - Machine      151
2018-12-05    Whl-Sales/Gift-Card      NaN
2018-12-05                  Total  1439.77
2018-12-06             Cigarettes   377.96
2018-12-06                Tobacco   129.07
2018-12-06          Snack/Grocery   281.83
2018-12-06              Beverages   235.73
2018-12-06                   Milk        0
2018-12-06                 Coffee    29.32
2018-12-06                Solaray    12.99
2018-12-06         Prepared Foods    27.37
2018-12-06     International Food     9.99
2018-12-06                 Sweets        5
2018-12-06  Automotive/News Paper    32.92
2018-12-06      Lottery - Scratch      509
2018-12-06      Lottery - Machine      194
2018-12-06    Whl-Sales/Gift-Card      NaN
2018-12-06                  Total  1845.18
2018-12-07             Cigarettes   526.91
2018-12-07                Tobacco    65.71
2018-12-07          Snack/Grocery   202.27
2018-12-07              Beverages   183.59
2018-12-07                   Milk     2.79
2018-12-07                 Coffee    16.22
2018-12-07                Solaray     5.99
2018-12-07         Prepared Foods    24.98
2018-12-07     International Food     1.99
2018-12-07                 Sweets        0
2018-12-07  Automotive/News Paper    31.06
2018-12-07      Lottery - Scratch      300
2018-12-07      Lottery - Machine     61.5
2018-12-07    Whl-Sales/Gift-Card        0
2018-12-07                  Total  1423.01
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to `sum` the results? Try `df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Dept', values='Sales', aggfunc=sum)`

Comment: Is there any reason you have duplicate `Dept` and values for `2018-12-03` - is that to be expected?  What were your unexpected results?

Comment: Yeah the duplication is a good point, it is only done to this section... will check it out and let you know thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to set the index to `['Date', 'Dept']` and `unstack()` but you have multiple values for each `Dept` for the date `2018-12-03`.

Note sure if that is expected but one way to resolve that issues is to `groupby().first()` to take the first value and then `unstack()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
df.set_index(['Date', 'Dept']).groupby(level=[0, 1]).first().unstack()

Out []:
                           Sales                                                                                                                                                                           
Dept       Automotive/News Paper Beverages Cigarettes Coffee International Food Lottery - Machine Lottery - Scratch   Milk Prepared Foods Snack/Grocery Solaray Sweets Tobacco    Total Whl-Sales/Gift-Card
Date                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2018-12-01                 10.47    160.97    426.889  29.72              65.00            191.00            1397.0  11.56           3.99        198.57    9.99    0.0   43.84  2549.00                 0.0
2018-12-02                 13.16    135.28    374.010  33.76               3.98            211.00             651.0   9.57          20.98        178.01   17.99    0.0   89.29  1738.03                 0.0
2018-12-03                 70.17    126.01    463.540  30.47              21.98            461.00            1046.0   8.57           0.00        164.19   17.99    0.0   35.26  2445.18                 0.0
2018-12-04                 47.00    163.11    291.910  32.17               6.98            112.75             762.0   3.99           5.00        207.87   40.98    0.0   42.93  1716.69                 NaN
2018-12-05                 46.24     87.94    255.720  15.95              17.73            151.00             540.0   9.77           8.98        212.94   11.98    0.0   81.52  1439.77                 NaN
2018-12-06                 32.92    235.73    377.960  29.32               9.99            194.00             509.0   0.00          27.37        281.83   12.99    5.0  129.07  1845.18                 NaN
2018-12-07                 31.06    183.59    526.910  16.22               1.99             61.50             300.0   2.79          24.98        202.27    5.99    0.0   65.71  1423.01                 0.0
```

But this is almost identical to `df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Dept', values='Sales')`:

```
Dept        Automotive/News Paper  Beverages  Cigarettes  Coffee  International Food  Lottery - Machine  Lottery - Scratch   Milk  Prepared Foods  Snack/Grocery  Solaray  Sweets  Tobacco    Total  Whl-Sales/Gift-Card
Date                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2018-12-01                  10.47     160.97     426.889   29.72               65.00             191.00             1397.0  11.56            3.99         198.57     9.99     0.0    43.84  2549.00                  0.0
2018-12-02                  13.16     135.28     374.010   33.76                3.98             211.00              651.0   9.57           20.98         178.01    17.99     0.0    89.29  1738.03                  0.0
2018-12-03                  70.17     126.01     463.540   30.47               21.98             461.00             1046.0   8.57            0.00         164.19    17.99     0.0    35.26  2445.18                  0.0
2018-12-04                  47.00     163.11     291.910   32.17                6.98             112.75              762.0   3.99            5.00         207.87    40.98     0.0    42.93  1716.69                  NaN
2018-12-05                  46.24      87.94     255.720   15.95               17.73             151.00              540.0   9.77            8.98         212.94    11.98     0.0    81.52  1439.77                  NaN
2018-12-06                  32.92     235.73     377.960   29.32                9.99             194.00              509.0   0.00           27.37         281.83    12.99     5.0   129.07  1845.18                  NaN
2018-12-07                  31.06     183.59     526.910   16.22                1.99              61.50              300.0   2.79           24.98         202.27     5.99     0.0    65.71  1423.01                  0.0
```